# How can I programaticaly create a directory on file upload and save the uploaded file to that direcotry using django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a directory programmatically on file upload. I'm able to create the directory using date and time stamp at the same time the file also getting uploaded. But I'm not able to save the file inside the directory during the upload.

My views.py

```
def uploadfile(request):
    dirname = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S') 

    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        os.mkdir(os.path.join('uploads', dirname)) #'uploads' is my media root folder
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file) ##** this file need to be saved inside the /uploads/2010.08.09.12.08.45/files_name **##
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

The above code uploads the file using the form from the template using POST and the and it also creates a folder with current timestamp. But the issue is that I'm not able to save the file inside the folder.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def uploadfile(request):
    dirname = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S') 

    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        folder='uploads/{name}/file_name'.format(dirname) 
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=folder)
        os.mkdir(os.path.join('uploads', dirname)) 
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

Comment: if the line folder='uploads/{name}/file_name'.format(dirname) is changed to folder='uploads/'+dirname.format(dirname) it works perfectly.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the following worked fine for me.

```
def uploadfile(request):
    dirname = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S') #2010.08.09.12.08.45 
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=dirname)
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```